How to extract GPIO pin TTL ratings for this MCU?
I'm using a MCU board with this MCU and following pinout:

Now the datasheet is huge and I couldn't figure out how to extract an information I need. In my case, I use PA2 and PB4 pins as UART TX RX. And I so far connected them to 3.3V TTL devices. My question is can these pins handle 5V TTL? It is not very clear to me how to read the datasheet and conclude these pins are 5.5V compatible?
Update:
After reading great answers and comments, I concluded I can use the TX RX pins with 5V since RX is 5V tolerant and TX will be 3.3V output to MAX485 which can work with 3.3V.
(Click on images to enlarge the view)
Then the question was the voltage at RX pin of the MCU should not exceed VDD+4V. In my case I power the MAX485 board and the MCU board from +5V pin. And there is a pin on the MCU board which is connected to VDD. So I decided the monitor what happens during power ON and OFF by using a scope.
Orange plot is the PB4 RX pin and the blue plot is the VDD pin of the MCU.
During power ON:

During power OFF:

I also made the same comparison between 5V supply(red) and the VDD(blue):
During turn ON:

During turn OFF:


What device(s) are you connecting it to? Are the signals old school 5V TTL as such, or (LV)CMOS resembling it?

@TimWilliams I want t use it with MAX485. It seems MAX485 requires 5V supply. And I guess it makes it 5V TTL. So Im afraid if I will damage the MCU pins(PA2 PB4). Hope your have your feedback.

MAX485 datasheet: https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/MAX1487-MAX491.pdf

I guess MAX485 is designed to operate with a supply voltage of 4.75V to 5.25V, so it is not directly compatible with a 3.3V VCC. Maybe I should find other MCU pins which are compatible with 5V TTL?

@cm64 Just by curiosity, why not have a separate supply rail, i.e. a boost converter, to power your transceiver? What's the maximum current draw of the transceiver and do you expect the GPIO pin handle that?

@Colin Thats what Im planning to do. I already use +5V pin to power the MCU board. Now I can use this to power the RMAXS485.

From the datasheet Table 12. Legend/abbreviations used in the pinout table has an I/O structure parameter where the FT or FTf abbreviations indicate a "5 V tolerant I/O":

For the pins in the question Table 13. STM32F303x6/8 pin definitions shows:




PA2 has I/O structure TTa and is therefore NOT 5 V tolerant.
PB4 has I/P structure FT and should therefore be 5 V tolerant.


Thank you. How do you figure out(infer) "PA2 has I/O structure TTa and is therefore NOT 5 V tolerant"? Is there a table for the pins?

@cm64 I have updated the answer with a screenshot of the table entries for the pins

Note that (from a now-deleted answer, but it should be easy to find in the datasheet under Absolute maximum ratings) the FT pins are only 5V tolerance if Vdd is 1V or more (Vdd+4V). If your 3.3V Vdd is derived from the 5V that should not be an issue, but if the 5V supply could be present without the 3.3V supply it could be an issue.

@ChesterGillon Thanks for great answer. Im planning to use it with MAX485 but MAX485 is designed to operate with a supply voltage of 4.75V to 5.25V, so it is not directly compatible with a 3.3V but only 5V TTL. So I guess I need to switch to another pin from PA2 to PB3. PB3 seem 5V tolerant.

@Spehro'speff'Pefhany "If your 3.3V Vdd is derived from the 5V that should not be an issue, but if the 5V supply could be present without the 3.3V supply it could be an issue" I dont quite get what you mean. I basically use this board https://docs.zephyrproject.org/latest/_images/nucleo_f303k8_pinout.jpg And power it from +5V pin. Now I want to use this pin to power the MAX485 as well. But MAX485 will now output 5V TTL. Would that be fine if I use 5V tolerant MCU pins?

If the same 5V supply powers both (the 3.3V regulator on your board and the MAX485) it is probably okay. But, personally, I'd probably put a voltage translator chip in there.

@Spehro'speff'Pefhany Thank you for answers and comments.  I tried it and it work from same supply. Please see my update. I plotted the VDD and RX voltages vs time during ON and OFF times. Hope to have your feedback.

PA2 TX is type TT so it will not handle 5V, but it does not need to as it is a 3.3V output. The 5V chip needs to deal with that, or you need level shifting. The MAX485 datasheet says it works with 3.3V inputs just fine.
PB4 RX is type FT so it is 5V tolerant.
However, the MCU absolute maximum ratings say that level after it damage is VDD+4.0V, so if MCU is unpowered with 0V VDD then 5V on PB4 will damage it.
So the pin can only handle 5.5V when MCU has supply voltage above 1.5V.
You may need power sequencing that MCU powers up first and 5V last. Same when power tuns off, 5V off first, then 3.3V. Or provide proper level shifting to guarantee the MCU is not damaged.

Indeed, sequencing doesn't need to be terribly strict; the supplies can come up at the same time, for example if 3.3V is derived via LDO from +5V, and the risetime is modest (a few ms?), it can be made to rise up at the same rate, and no levels are violated.  This is complicated, however, if overload conditions are ever expected (3.3V shorts out, 5V remains up). A voltage clamping strategy might be used to protect against that.

Thank you for answers and comments. Please see my update.
